# JavaFX 2 buttons size fill width and are each same width?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Working in Java FX 2.2.  The Scene has a horizontal width that is fixed but is unknown at compile time.  I want to place 2 or more buttons in a horizontal row that completely fills the horizontal space in the Scene AND that are each exactly the same width.  The number of buttons changes dynamically with the program state.  What program snippet will accomplish this?

Comment: Is it what you need?
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm#CJHDJDIF

Comment: Nope.  The buttons will vary in width as the program changes state.  When the program is in STATE1, there will only be three buttons.  After some action we move to STATE2 where there might be four buttons with different text.  Thus in STATE1 each button width should be the (scenewidth / 3), and in STATE 2 (scenewidth / 4).  Again, the text in the buttons is irrelevant to the size.  What matters is the width of the Scene and the number of buttons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code from the [HBox javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) will almost do what you want, except that "buttons themselves are different sizes based on the text contained in the button - wider text causes wider buttons".

```
HBox hbox = new HBox();
Button button1 = new Button("Add");
Button button2 = new Button("Remove");
HBox.setHgrow(button1, Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox.setHgrow(button2, Priority.ALWAYS);
button1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
button2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
hbox.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);
```

By creating a custom layout pane based on HBox and overriding it's layout method, you can get exactly the behaviour you describe.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// displays equal width buttons which fill a layout region's width.
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830402/javafx-2-buttons-size-fill-width-and-are-each-same-width
public class HorizontallyTiledButtons extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final Button addButton    = new Button("Add");
    final Button removeButton = new Button("Remove");
    final Button extraButton  = new Button("The wizard of Frobozz is watching");

    final ButtonBar buttonBar = new ButtonBar(5, addButton, removeButton);

    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        buttonBar.addButton(extraButton);
      }
    });

    removeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        buttonBar.removeButton(extraButton);
      }
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.getChildren().addAll(buttonBar);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");

    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.setWidth(800);
    stage.show();
  }

  class ButtonBar extends HBox {
    ButtonBar(double spacing, Button... buttons) {
      super(spacing);
      getChildren().addAll(buttons);
      for (Button b: buttons) {
        HBox.setHgrow(b, Priority.ALWAYS);
        b.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
      }
    }

    public void addButton(Button button) {
      HBox.setHgrow(button, Priority.ALWAYS);
      button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
      ObservableList<Node> buttons = getChildren();
      if (!buttons.contains(button)) {
        buttons.add(button);
      }
    }

    public void removeButton(Button button) {
      getChildren().remove(button);
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
      double minPrefWidth = calculatePrefChildWidth();
      for (Node n: getChildren()) {
        if (n instanceof Button) {
          ((Button) n).setMinWidth(minPrefWidth);
        }
      }
      super.layoutChildren();
    }

    private double calculatePrefChildWidth() {
      double minPrefWidth = 0;
      for (Node n: getChildren()) {
        minPrefWidth = Math.max(minPrefWidth, n.prefWidth(-1));
      }
      return minPrefWidth;
    }
  }
}
```

Sample program output:
[image: twobuttons]
[image: threebuttons]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It ALMOST works in the manner that I am looking for.  What I want is equal sized buttons.  This code creates buttons whose total size fills the entire width (that is what I want), but the buttons themselves are different sizes based on the text contained in the button - wider text causes wider buttons.

Comment: Added a further sample which seems to do what you are asking.

Comment: jewelsea - My previous comment was based on your first response which only included the code snippet that did ALMOST what I wanted.  Your latest edit of your response looks like it does exactly what I'm looking for.  I assume it works - I'll get a chance to test it later, but for now I'll mark your comment as answering my question.  Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Hi, I'm from 2 years later. :-) Would this solution apply to a `GridPane` as well? e.g. custom grid with resizable children, both width&height.

Comment: @GGrec No, a GridPane is a more complex structure and this solution would not apply directly to a GridPane.  I wrote an [application which provides a resizable, tiled grid of buttons](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2030464) a long time ago, which sounds more applicable to your use case.

Answer (score 15):

A bit cleaner solution with property binding:

```
    HBox buttonLayout = new HBox();
    buttonLayout.getChildren().add(button1);
    buttonLayout.getChildren().add(button2);

    int btnCount = buttonLayout.getChildren().size();
    button1.prefWidthProperty().bind(buttonLayout.widthProperty().divide(btnCount));
    button2.prefWidthProperty().bind(buttonLayout.widthProperty().divide(btnCount));
```

Comment: This works great, although it seemed to work fine without the `HBox.setHgrow` statements

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I removed the setHgrow part.

Comment: This one is so clean. Thanks :)