# Javafx Custom Pane Layout Children

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I am trying to create a custom pane in javafx that holds a group of buttons.
The pane auto lays out the buttons so that they take up the maximum allowable width.

The pane works great, the problem I am having is that when the scene is set on the stage, the buttons lay out, but are off the screen to the bottom.

Any action I make on the stage (including clicking another windows and de-focusing the stage) causes them to lay out correctly.

I can't figure out what is going on.
I want to post a screenshot of what is happening, the problem is as mentioned when I go to take the screenshot, the window de-focuses and the bar then lays out correctly.

```
public class ButtonBar extends Pane {

//Add to auto generated buttons
protected String buttonPrefix = "F";
protected String buttonSuffix = "";


//Container sizing
protected DoubleProperty prefHeight = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

//Button Sizing
protected DoubleProperty buttonWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
protected DoubleProperty buttonHeight = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

//Button Positioning
protected ArrayList<DoubleProperty> buttonXLocation;

//Static Button sizing
protected double interButtonMargin = 1;
protected double endButtonMargin = 10;

//Store whether initialized
protected boolean initialized = false;

//Listen for change to relayout
InvalidationListener layoutListener;

public int getNumberButtons() {
    return numberButtons;
}

public void setNumberButtons(int numberButtons) {
    this.numberButtons = numberButtons;
}

//Number of buttons
protected int numberButtons = 12;

protected boolean respectApsectRatio = true;


public ButtonBar() {
    this(12);
}

public ButtonBar(List<Button> buttons) {
    this.numberButtons = buttons.size();
    getChildren().addAll(buttons);
}


public ButtonBar(int numButtons) {
    this.numberButtons = numButtons;

    for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        button.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 7; -fx-font-size: 30px; -fx-background-color: #ffb366");
        getChildren().add(button);
    }

}

protected void init() {
    buttonXLocation = new ArrayList<DoubleProperty>(numberButtons);

    List<Node> children = getChildren();

    //Calculate button width minus paddings
    buttonWidth.bind(
            widthProperty()
                    .subtract(interButtonMargin * (numberButtons - 1))
                    .subtract(endButtonMargin * 2)
                    .divide(numberButtons)
    );

    if (!respectApsectRatio) {
        buttonHeight.bind(heightProperty());
        prefHeight.bind(heightProperty());
    } else {
        buttonHeight.bind(buttonWidth);
        prefHeight.bind(buttonHeight);
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (Node n : getChildren()) {
        Button b = (Button) n;

        DoubleProperty buttonX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        buttonX.bind(buttonWidth
                .multiply(i)
                .add(endButtonMargin)
                .add(interButtonMargin * i)
        );

        buttonXLocation.add(i, buttonX);

        //Set button text
        b.setText(buttonPrefix + b.getText() + buttonSuffix);

        i++;
    }

    setNeedsLayout(true);
    this.initialized = true;

    layoutListener = new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            setNeedsLayout(true);
            layout();
            layoutChildren();
        }
    };


    widthProperty().addListener(layoutListener);
    heightProperty().addListener(layoutListener);


}


@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    //Only initialize once
    if( !initialized ) init();

    super.layoutChildren();

    setPrefHeight(prefHeight.doubleValue());

    List<Node> buttons = getChildren();
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
        Button button = (Button) buttons.get(i);

        button.setPrefWidth(buttonWidth.doubleValue());
        button.setPrefHeight(buttonHeight.doubleValue());
        button.setLayoutX(buttonXLocation.get(i).doubleValue());
        button.setLayoutY(0);
    }

    super.layoutChildren();
}`
```

Comment: Just some comments. I don't recommend doing layout calculations using both binding and also overriding layoutChildren.  Instead, just do it one way or the other, and in your case probably just handling layout only in layoutChildren is probably best.  Also no need to have your own prefHeight variable, all resizable nodes such as Pane already have one.  You also don't need a layout listener, layoutChildren will automatically be invoked when the pane needs to be laid out.  Don't set the prefHeight in layoutChildren, there is an overridable computePrefHeight method for calculating that.

Comment: I'm curious if a standard HBox with appropriate constraints will work for you.  Perhaps this question is just a duplicate of: [JavaFX 2 buttons size fill width and are each same width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830402/javafx-2-buttons-size-fill-width-and-are-each-same-width)